# Event that fires when a control gets added onto another control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, size, parent

Is there an event that gets fired when a user control gets added onto a `Form`?
I need this to get the size of the `Parent` control of the user control.

But when the user control gets initialized etc, the `Parent = null`.
Because the user control hasn't been added yet onto the Form. So i can't get the Parent control (which is the Form) at this point.

So i'll have to do the re-sizing of the user control afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [ParentChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged.aspx) event that all Controls inherit.  In the event handler method you can inspect the Parent property, which will be set to the new parent at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Control.ParentChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged.aspx) event. This will fire whenever the parent of the control is changed, so you can check if the parent is the form and then continue with how you want to react.

Alternatively, you can use the [Control.ControlAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

You have the ControlAdded event on the form, wich is initialized in your InitializeComponent(). Most of the time this event is duely placed after the adding of components. If you place it before the adding of UserControls to the form you will fire events each time you add a component.

I would recommend adding the usercontrol you need such specific control over in your codebehind and not move the eventhandler.

If you do that you can add a parent to your usercontrol which might give you the information you need.

```
var textBox = new TextBox {Parent = this};
```